# Read document from encrypted zone of Hadoop using java

Tags: java, hadoop, encryption

I have been trying to read a file from encrytped HDFS zone in Cloudera Hadoop using a java client. Using the web consoIe of Hive I can see the file and I have java code that can read files from not encrypted HDFS folders but this code is not working when is trying to read from an encrypted zone. From [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cdh_sg_hdfs_encryption.html) of cloudera. I understand that the client does not need to do anything to desencrypt the file. But I believe that I need to configure the client to be able to see the kms. I had tried with:

> configuration.set(KeyProviderFactory.KEY_PROVIDER_PATH,                   kms://https@server.intranet.org;server.intranet.org:1XXXX/kms");
>   And
>   configuration.set(KeyProviderFactory.KEY_PROVIDER_PATH,                   "https://server.intranet.org:1XXXX/kms");

Does some one know if I am doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"Does some one know..."_ > without any error message in your post? You are not asking for knowkedge, but for divination...

Comment: I did not put the log because I did not think that it would provide more information than I have already put in the post. This is the log: